# Java - Converting data handler to file is time consuming

Tags: java, wav

I need to send the audio file the from client to the server. So I have a REST API for which the attachment is the input. I need to convert this attachment to audio file in the Java layer. I tried two different ways but both are time consuming. Any suggestions?

Method1:

```
File tempFile=File.createTempFile("tempFile", ".wav");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
DataHandler handler = attachemnt.getDataHandler();
InputStream Filestream = handler.getInputStream();

if (Filestream.available()>10) {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = Filestream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    out.close();
    Filestream.close();
}
```

Method2:

```
File tempFile=File.createTempFile("tempFile", ".wav");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
DataHandler handler = attachment.getDataHandler();
InputStream is = handler.getInputStream();
if (is.available() > 10) {
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    // This will copy the file from the two streams
    IOUtils.copy(is, os);

    // This will close two streams catching exception
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}
```

Comment: you're probably blocked on I/O. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: using BufferedOutputStream maybe could improve your IO, however you should do some profiling to be sure what REALLY takes your time